# Disable Ability to Change Language with Spacebar

Tags: languages, gboard

I have a Pixel 4 with Android 10.  I am new to Android.

I use both English and Spanish.  I want to be able hold down the Spacebar to enter the mode where I can move the cursor around.

But when I do so, I get a pop-up asking me to switch languages.  Since I can accomplish the same thing with the globe button, how can I disable this? Thanks

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: As a long-time Gboard user, I don't think there's a way to disable this feature. On the other hand, to use "slide to move cursor", you need to hold then quickly slide the finger to move the cursor. It's doable.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea I know how you feel I was an apple user but as Andrew.T states just touch where you want the cursor and drag and you will get to where you need to be. hold your finger down for longer you get copy paste etc etc :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But you lose the ability to switch languages. So it depends what's a priority for you. Since I'm monolingual I have no need to switch languages and I have disabled the space bar language pop up.

The way to do it is to go into the language settings and delete all but one language. In my case I had to disable handwriting US English as well as another version of US English which uses a the keyboard layout that I never bother with. So I'm left with only one option and that is US English QWERTY. If you do something like that then the space bar can be used solely for moving the cursor by sliding or creating a space.